# Combine properties in one attribute or split into more attributes?

Tags: c#, attributes

In C#, I started using attributes to define my class. I'm writing a plugin system in which classes require some metadata to be recognized as plugins.

I don't know exactly anymore how the Visual Studio Extensions did it, but I require an opinion or design rule which tells me if I should create an attribute with many (optional) parameters or use more attributes with less parameters.

For example, the decision is about these two different code pieces:

Single attribute, many properties:

```
[Plugin("Image Tools", Author = "PacMani", Description = "blahblah",
    Website = "http://blahblah.contoso.com/", Image = "Icon32x32.png")]
public class ImagePlugin : Plugin
{
    // ...
}
```

versus

```
[Plugin("Image Tools", Author = "PacMani", Description = "blahblah")]
[Website("http://blahblah.contoso.com/")]
[Image("Icon32x32.png")]
public class ImagePlugin : Plugin
{
    // ...
}
```

or even a version which splits up "Author" and "Description" into single attributes.

My idea was to not split thematically grouped attributes. But where do such groups start and end? The above properties are all of the group "Details" or "Descriptive information" about the plugin.

Comment: Is there any logic connected with these attributes or are they only informative?

Comment: In the example above, they are required to present information about the Plugin in the IDE loading them at the end (similar to the VS info dialog). I can imagine that some more attributes will be added later on, like "Version" for example, which will probably not be optional.

Comment: If they will all be used each time any of them are used, then you should use a single attribute.

Comment: Okay, that would speak for the first example, since they are loaded when getting information about the plugin. You'd agree to add another attribute like "[FileExtensions(".png", ".jpg")] to describe the file types it can handle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I would recommend to put all these informative pieces of data as one attribute. Why? Because :

- They are all connected with one concept - plugin
- They are only informative

It would probably be different if there would be some logic connected with each of the property- then  would consider splitting them.

There is one other scenario you might be willing to split these into separate attributes - in case you can logically separate the types of plugins. So then you could have a base PluginAttribute with only basic properties, then e.g. ImagePluginAttribute attribute which inherits from PluginAttribute and has some additional properties, etc. 
But I would not divide it into separate attributes by properties (WebsiteAttribute, AuthorAttribute, VersionAttribute) in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Might of misunderstood the problem ,but why not use a config file? seems more appropriate then attributes in this case no?
You can recognize the classes as plugins by their inheritance, and the rest of the metadata in those attributes seems like just meta data that should be defined as either properties in the class or config for easy access (if they change outside of the code - stuff like website).

Comment: They should not be changed outside, they just describe the class as compiled.